# Function sees old value on state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make test app, just a simple address book.

I'm almost done but right now I have one problem with selecting items from the FlatList.

When I longPress an contact it fires the onLongPress function, it marks that contact as selected and saves a list of selected contacts with `this.setState({selectedContacts})`

The problem is when I tap on a contact, if there's already one selected it should keep selecting, if no contact has been selected it should enter that contact details screen.

The problem is that on the onPress function `this.state.selectedContacts.length` is always 0.

```
onPress(contact) {
  console.log("Contacts Selected:",this.state.selectedContacts.length);
  if (this.state.selectedContacts.length < 1) {
    console.log("navigating");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ContactDetails', {
      id: `${contact.id}`,
    });
  } else {
    this.toggleSelection(contact);
  }
  console.log("onPress",this.state.selectedContacts);
}

onLongPress(contact) {
  toggleSelection(contact);
  console.log("onLongPress",this.state.selectedContacts);
}

toggleSelection(contact) {
    contact.isSelected = !contact.isSelected;

    selectedContacts = [];

    this.state.contacts.map(function(contact){
      if (contact.isSelected){
        selectedContacts[contact.id] = contact.facebook_url;
      }
    });

    this.setState({selectedContacts});
}

<TouchableOpacity style={listItemStyle}
                  onPress={() => this.onPress(contact)} 
                  onLongPress={() => this.onLongPress(contact)}>
    <Image source={{ uri: contact.icon }} style={styles.itemListAvatar} />
    <View style={styles.itemListText}>
        <Text style={styles.itemListName}>
            {contact.name}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemListDescription}>
            {contact.description}
        </Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're ambiguously using an array as an object:

```
toggleSelection(contact) {
    contact.isSelected = !contact.isSelected;

    selectedContacts = [];

    this.state.contacts.map(function(contact){
      if (contact.isSelected){
        selectedContacts[contact.id] = contact.facebook_url;
      }
    });

    this.setState({selectedContacts});
}
```

To add an item to a javascript array, you must use the Array.prototype.push method otherwise the length won't change (not exactly true, details below).

The thing is is JS `typeof [] === 'object` so you can write arr[newKeyThatMayNotBeANumber] to add the `newKeyThatMayNotBeANumber` property to the arr object, but by doing so, you won't always increase the array length.

Because JS is too kind, it will actually change the size of the array if `newKeyThatMayNotBeANumber` is interpretable as a number (ie: is a number, or a base10 string representation of a number).

But it will fail to do so otherwise. So it is a good habit to use actual object (`{}`) for key adressing, and array mutation methods (or strict number index access) for arrays.

**Console output in Chrome demonstating this kind of problem:**

```
const arr = [];
console.log(arr.length)
=> 0
arr['128'] = 'a';
console.log(arr)
=> [empty × 128, "a"]
console.log(arr.length)
=> 129
arr['bar'] = 'a';
console.log(arr)
=> (129) [empty × 128, "a", bar: "a"]
console.log(arr.length)
=> 129
```

That said, is contact.id always a number?

Comment: I see, since I need to store key and value would it be better to use an object and iterate with something like Object.keys?

Comment: Yes, Object.Keys is a good way of iterating properties of an object

Comment: contact.id is a uuid

Comment: Also as Andres below said, you shouldn't `map` an array if you're not using the new array instance it returns, use `forEach` instead.

Answer (score -1):

React relies on refs. So, when you mutate your state and then try to set it, nothing happens. There is a rule - state should be immutable. Try to create new instance of your array instead of mutating old one:

```js
const newSelectedContacts = selectedContacts.slice();
newSelectedContacts[contact.id] = contact.facebook_url;

this.setState({selectedContacts: newSelectedContacts});
```

also your `.map()` call looks useless - you're just assigning the same value to the same array item several times =)

Comment: The OP is already creating new arrays when updating the state, it is not a problem with mutating the state but rather an ill way of adding items into the array